# How to correctly implement delay in Spring Integration Flow

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am trying to implement a delay in a Spring Integration Flow.
I have one flow that is starting a process on another server and then I am checking after a delay if that process is completed or not.
When completed the flow should move to the next phase.
This seems to work it also shows in logs (and, clearly, in the flow itself), a long list of repetitions in the **runexampleScriptWaiting** channel.

I tried removing that channel change but then the flow gets stuck in that phase forever, never moving to completion.

How can I implement this so that a single runexampleScriptWaiting is shown / executed (something similar to a non-blocking while loop, I guess)?

I considered keeping it as is and just update my monitoring application (a very small frontend that shows which channels are in the payload's history) in order to get rid of duplicated channel lines but I also wondered if there is a better / more robust way to do this.

Here's a simplified example:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow exampleIntegrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(exampleConfig.runexampleScript.get())
            .<ExamplePayload>handle((payload, messageHeaders) -> examplePayloadService
                    .changeExampleServiceRequestStatus(payload, ExampleServiceStatus.STARTED))
            .<ExamplePayload>handle(
                    (payload, messageHeaders) -> exampleScriptService.runexample(payload))
            .channel(exampleConfig.runexampleScriptWaiting.get())
            .<ExamplePayload, Boolean>route(jobStatusService::areJobsFinished,
                    router -> router
                            .subFlowMapping(true, exampleSuccessSubflow())
                            .subFlowMapping(false, exampleWaitSubflow())
                            .defaultOutputToParentFlow()
            )
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow exampleWaitSubflow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(exampleConfig.runexampleScriptWaiting.get())
            .<ExamplePayload>handle(
                    (payload, messageHeaders) -> {
                        interruptIgnoringSleep(1000);
                        return payload;
                    })
            .channel(exampleConfig.runexampleScriptWaiting.get()) // Commenting this gets the process stuck
            .get();

}
```

Comment: Q: What's the best way implement a delay in a Spring Integration Flow?  A: DON'T DO IT.  "Polling" is Evil.  Avoid it if at all possible. Consider using an [ApplicationEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/event.html) instead.

Comment: Hi @paulsm4 and thanks for your contribution.
As Artem Bilan already pointed out in a comment to his answer this flow is starting a process on another server and that server is never notifying about the completion of the process.
For this reason the only possible way to know its status is fetching it from the server where the process is running.
Once status is complete the flow can proceed to the next phase.
While far from optimal this is indeed a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is your `exampleConfig.runexampleScriptWaiting.get()`, but what you have so far in the config is not OK. You have two subscribers to the same channel:

1. `.channel(exampleConfig.runexampleScriptWaiting.get())` and the next `route()`
2. `.from(exampleConfig.runexampleScriptWaiting.get())` and the next `handle()`

This may cause unexpected behavior, e.g. round-robin messages distribution.

I would do `filter()` and `delay()` instead in addition to an `ExecutorChannel` since you are asking about non-blocking retry:

```
.channel(exampleConfig.runexampleScriptWaiting.get())
.filter(jobStatusService::areJobsFinished, 
            filter -> filter.discardFlow(
                          discardFlow -> discardFlow
                                            .delay(1000)
                                            .channel(exampleConfig.runexampleScriptWaiting.get())))
```

The `exampleSuccessSubflow` could go just after this `filter()` as part of this flow or via `to(exampleSuccessSubflow())`.

Pay attention to that `discardFlow`: we delay non-finished message a little bit and produce it back to that `runexampleScriptWaiting` channel for calling this filter again. If you make this channel as an `ExecutorChannel` (or `QueueChannel`), your wait functionality is going to be non-blocking. But at the same time your main flow is still going to be blocked for this request since you continue waiting for reply.  Therefore it might not make too much sense to make this filtering logic as non-blocking and you can still use that `Thread.sleep()` instead of `delay()`.

The router solution also may work, but you cannot use that `runexampleScriptWaiting` channel as an input of that sub-flow. Probably that's the reason behind that your problem with "process stuck".

Comment: sleep() and delay() are equally poor choices.  The OP should probably consider an event-driven design, if at all possible...

Comment: When there is no event on the server side to notify us, we don't have choice unless poll the server periodically. The `sleep` and `delay` are good compromises to not overhead the server with our expectations. Since we don't have enough info about the target architecture, we form our answer according the current context and OP requests.

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan
Thanks for your answer, I implemented it and it works great, I am currently running tests.
I would love to understand more about its underlying logic, please allow me to ask a few questions about it.

Comment: In order to allow other flows to use our poller threads, I use that delay() instead of Thread.sleep().
The total waiting time for this loop can be _hours_ in some cases. Half an hour is the most common case.
I see that using your solution the poller threads are now indeed doing other things and this is indeed matching my functional need.
In the old implementation (a loop that had a check and a delay in it, without a channel in between) they would just be blocked.
I am just wondering: the check is now done on a scheduler thread.
Not on a poller thread. Is this a problem?

Comment: I wonder if this will make sizing the poller thread pool harder / less predictable because part of the flows are now running on the scheduler thread and the jobStatusService::areJobsFinished also takes about 15 seconds.
Should I add an extra channel right after exampleConfig.runexampleScriptWaiting.get() to make sure that jobStatusService::areJobsFinished runs on a poller thread instead?
Just in case I am missing something obvious here...
Do the poller threads and the scheduler threads happen to be on the same thread pool?

Comment: That’s correct: the poller and delayer are really sharing the same task scheduler. You can shift the load to an executor channel just after delay to free the scheduler thread for other tasks